# Django,Docker - Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed

Tags: python, django, docker

I`m trying deploy the Django project for productions.I use Postgres, Nginx and Gunicorn.
In a Docker container I have installed package Pillow==8.3.1 (I also tried version 8.3.0). In Dockerfile I have dependencies:

```
RUN apk update \
   && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY . .

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt
```

when I execute the migrate command:

```
docker-compose exec web python3 manage.py migrate
```

Shows me errors:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
poszukiwania.Rzeczy.image_obverse: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
poszukiwania.Rzeczy.image_reverse: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Add Pillow to your requirements.txt file

Comment: Collecting Pillow==8.3.0
  Downloading Pillow-8.3.0.tar.gz (48.5 MB) I had it installed

Comment: Try rebuilding your docker after adding Pillow in requirements.txt

Comment: @KaushalSharma I still have errors

Comment: `pip uninstall PIL`
`pip uninstall Pillow`
`pip install Pillow==8.3.0`  try this

Comment: Can you specify Python/Django version you are using?

Comment: @kamran890 Python==3.8.10, Django==3.1.6

Comment: When I use the development server. Everything work. Instead of 'pip' in Dockerfile I took  'python3 -m pip' and no changes :( Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ding the answer ? I am having the exact same problem. Thanks